sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/d NTFS signature is missingi cant access to my partitions after come from windows
When I installed Ubuntu, I deleted Disk C, and the installation was successful. But Disk D and Disk E didn't show. I mounted Disk D as /mnt/d as an NTFS partition. After that, nothing shows, and I can't access. It shows error: NTFS signature is missing.
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/d
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/nvme0n1p3': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/nvme0n1p3' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: INTEL SSDPEKKF512G7L                    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9f922738

Device         Boot     Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1           2048     978943    976896   477M 83 Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p2         978944  420661247 419682304 200.1G 83 Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p3 *    420661248  790292479 369631232 176.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/nvme0n1p4      790292480 1000212479 209920000 100.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Did you leave the NTFS partitions in hibernated or fast startup state which sets hibernation flag. Best not to use NTFS unless you are dual booting with Windows as NTFS will need chkdsk or defrag which cannot be done from Linux. You may be able to repair NTFS with a Windows repair/recovery flash drive or installer with repair console. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Use ntfsfix -d /dev/nvme0n1p3 ntfsfix /dev/nvme0n1p4
